# Dynamically traverse and update JSON values in Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing, dynamic

I need to dynamically update the JSON values using Scala. I would not know JSON structure in advance, it would change per user. The user will input the JSON from some file and also provide values for which keys, in nested form, need to be updated. For updating values, I would be calling a library, for simplicity let's say I want to reverse the values.

Input JSON (can be any JSON though):

```
{
    "emp_data": [{
            "employee": {
                "name": "sonoo",
                "salary": 56000,
                "desig": "Manager"
            }
        },
        {
            "employee": {
                "name": "monoo",
                "salary": 66000,
                "desig": "Engineer"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version:": 10.1,
    "Dept": "HR",
    "contact": {
        "email": "sean@3dx.com",
        "phone": ["+1 9876543210", "+1 8976543210"]
    }
}
```

Keys to be updated : `emp_data.employee.name, contact.phone` (can be any keys based on input JSON)

The output I need is :

```
 {
    "emp_data": [{
            "employee": {
                "name": "oonos",
                "salary": 56000,
                "desig": "Manager"
            }
        },
        {
            "employee": {
                "name": "oonom",
                "salary": 66000,
                "desig": "Engineer"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version:": 10.1,
    "Dept": "HR",
    "contact": {
        "email": "sean@3dx.com",
        "phone": ["0123456789 1+", "0123456798"]
    }
}
```

Please suggest some efficient approaches

Comment: The function you need to apply will leave the structure of the json untouched?

Comment: yes, the structure/order should remain the same as the original JSON.

Comment: You can use a JSON library like **circe** or **upickle** which allows you to traverse and modify the JSON object.

Comment: Or play-json transformers

Comment: Appreciate some code examples without hardcoding the key names. The examples I could find are based on knowing the structure in advance.

Comment: @JSC take a look at [this](https://circe.github.io/circe/cursors.html#transforming-data) go on a try to give it a go if you get stuck feel free to edit this question _(or open a new one)_ including details like the library used, which version, and the code you wrote and which problems you found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch that may give you an idea how it could be implemented. It requires [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/). The code is incomplete, not stack safe and could be optimised in many aspects (e.g. to avoid recreating jsons when there are no modifications). It covers only `emp_data.employee.name` key and not `contact.phone`. You need to put some effort into designing paths' rules or the code will become very complex if you want to cover all edge cases (e.g. how could I know that you expect to go into an array and modify it's elements when I've already followed the full path).

```scala
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._

// Recursively traversing the json along the given path.
def findAndReplace(in: Json, path: List[String], f: Json => Option[Json]): Json = {
  (path match {
    case h :: Nil =>
      // the transformation function f is applied only to objects' fields
      in.asObject.filter(_.contains(h)).flatMap { obj =>
        obj(h).flatMap(f).map { newVal => Json.fromJsonObject(obj.add(h, newVal)) }
      }
    case h :: remainingPath if in.isArray =>
      // if it's an array then we get inside and leave the path unchanged
      in.asArray.filter(_.nonEmpty).map { items =>
        Json.fromValues(items.map( item => findAndReplace(item, path, f) ))
      }
    case h :: remainingPath if in.isObject =>
      // the object has to have a field with name as the head of the path to continue traverse
      in.asObject.flatMap { obj =>
        obj(h).map { oldVal =>
          val newVal = findAndReplace(oldVal, remainingPath, f)
          Json.fromJsonObject(obj.add(h, newVal))
        }
      }
    // stop traversing for other cases
    case _ => None
  }).getOrElse(in)
}

// Function for applying the same function f to multiple paths 
def findAndReplaceAll(in: Json, paths: List[List[String]], f: Json => Option[Json]): Json = {
  // we go through whole json for each path
  paths.foldLeft(in) { case (newJson, path) =>
    findAndReplace(newJson, path, f)
  }
}


val json = parse(input).toOption.get

val newJson = findAndReplaceAll(
  json,
  List(List("emp_data", "employee", "name"), List("contact", "phone")),
  { _.asString.map(_.reverse).map(Json.fromString) }
)

println(json.noSpaces)
println(newJson.noSpaces)
```

Comment: Thanks, @michaJIS, it is very helpful, can modify if needed. 